# How do you pass search results to another view for displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a set of search results, i'm starting with 10 sets for now but plan to expand

EX:

Title: Awesome Title

Description: Boring Description Blah Blah Blah

URL: http://www.thePlaceToFindStuffOrWhatever.com/Awesome%20Title

Currently i am just logging them brainstorming with the quickest simplest way to store them together so they can be sent to another view and processed in a table.

I've Thought about Starting an NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary and putting each set into in array but I would like to keep it with the Title: or Description: part for easy displaying of data

Maybe I could put NSDictionaries inside of an array so i could do something like

```
 for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in resultsArray) {
     //find title, description, and url here
}
```

So whats the most efficient way of going about this? and if you could point me in the direction of a tutorial for it or provide sample code

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use a model class with init with coders and decoders?

Comment: I've switched to that by now thanks, i've learned a lot by now and really enjoy classes at this point. This question is 3 years old i completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

Structures could help! http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_structures.htm

You put each structure into a NSMutableArray and it will be easy to fetch items.